# PowerShell Script with SQL Server Query not returning result

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2014, powershell-4.0

I've got a simple PowerShell (v.4) script that I am running to get a single value from a table in one of my SQL Server databases. The issue seems to be the query. I can run the query on on the server from SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and get the result I need. When I attempt to get the value in PowerShell, store it into a variable and then write it to the screen, nothing is written.

I'm new to PowerShell, so I can't tell if the lack of a value means it is returning null/not getting a result set, or that my script is missing something.

Here is the script that I am running (Server and DB redacted):

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=XXXXXXXXX;Database=XXXXX;Integrated Security=True"

$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCmd = $SqlConnection.CreateCommand()
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT [ap_app_key] FROM [XXXXX].[dbo].[ws_app] WHERE ap_version = '20160909'"

$Result = $SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
Write-Host $Result
$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Thank you for any insights.

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: Is it possible that there is interference from SQL Server? Could there be some setting I need to change that allows remote querying?

Comment: Sure, but I'd expect `$SqlConnection.Open()` or `$SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()` to throw an error then.  Try changing your query to `$SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT GETDATE() AS DATE_TEST"`, and try executing the query with SSMS.

Comment: Very strange, I did get the error about remote connections with this query. I'll talk to my sysadmins. Thank you!